# Rate of change of surface area of a sphere given the rate of change of the radius

Tags: derivatives

Air is pumped into a spherical balloon such that the radius of the balloon increases at the rate of $\dfrac{1}{20}\pi$ cm/s when the radius is $8.5 \text{cm}$. Find the rate of change of the surface area of the balloon at this instant.

How do I do this? I still don't really understand how rate of change works here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface area $S$ is related to the radius $r$ *via*

$S = 4\pi r^2; \tag 1$

thus, $\dot S$ is related to $\dot r$ *via*

$\dot S = 8\pi r \dot r; \tag 2$

when

$r = 8.5 \; \text{cm.} \tag 3$

and

$\dot r = \dfrac{1}{20 \pi} \; \text{cm./sec.}, \tag 4$

we have

$\dot S = 8 \pi (8.5) \dfrac{1}{20\pi} = \dfrac{68}{20} \; \text{cm.^2/sec.} = \dfrac{17}{5}  \; \text{cm.^2/sec.}. \tag 5$

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what does S˙=8πrr mean? Why isn't it S=8πr?

Comment: Take the derivative of $S = 4\pi r^2$ with respect to $t$.  Note that $d(r^2)/dt = 2r\dot r$.